# Dovecot running but it shows some services command startup failed

Tags: dovecot

My Dovecot 's running, but some services seem not work. Below are the services that not working.

```
Jun 05 10:05:27 xxx.com systemd[1]: Started Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
Jun 05 10:05:27 xxx.com dovecot[16102]: master: Error: service(lmtp): command startup failed, throttling for 2.000 secs
Jun 05 10:05:27 xxx.com dovecot[16102]: master: Error: service(anvil): command startup failed, throttling for 2.000 secs
Jun 05 10:05:27 xxx.com dovecot[16102]: master: Error: service(pop3-login): command startup failed, throttling for 2.000 secs
Jun 05 10:05:27 xxx.com dovecot[16102]: master: Error: service(imap-login): command startup failed, throttling for 2.000 secs
Jun 05 10:05:27 xxx.com dovecot[16102]: master: Error: service(managesieve-login): command startup failed, throttling for 2.000 secs
Jun 05 10:05:27 xxx.com dovecot[16102]: log: Fatal: Dovecot version mismatch: Master is v2.3.17, log is v2.3.19 (if you don't care, set version_ignore=yes)
Jun 05 10:05:27 xxx.com dovecot[16102]: master: Error: service(log): child 16110 returned error 89 (Fatal failure)
Jun 05 10:05:27 xxx.com dovecot[16102]: master: Error: service(log): command startup failed, throttling for 2.000 secs
Jun 05 10:05:27 xxx.com dovecot[16102]: master: Error: service(config): command startup failed, throttling for 2.000 secs
```

I tried to change the service configuration in 10-master.conf but not work.

Below is my work.

```
   #default_process_limit = 100
#default_client_limit = 1000

#default_vsz_limit = 256M

#default_login_user = dovenull

#default_internal_user = dovecot

service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
   #port = 993
   #ssl = yes
  }

  # service_count = 1
  # process_min_avail = 0
  # vsz_limit = $default_vsz_limit
}

service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 110
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    #port = 995
    #ssl = yes
  }

service submission-login {
  inet_listener submission {
    #port = 587
  }
}

service lmtp {
  unix_listener lmtp {
    mode = 0666
  }

  #inet_listener lmtp {
    # Avoid making LMTP visible for the entire internet
    #address =
    #port =
  }
}

service imap {
  # vsz_limit = $default_vsz_limit
  # process_limit = 1024
}

service pop3 {
  # process_limit = 1024
}

service submission {
  # process_limit = 1024
}

service auth {
unix_listener auth-userdb {
    #mode = 0666
    #user =
    #group =
  }

  # Postfix smtp-auth
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }

  # user = $default_internal_user
}

service auth-worker {
  # user = root
}

service dict {
  unix_listener dict {
    #mode = 0600
    #user =
    #group =
  }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Regards,

Comment: `version mismatch`? You might want to check if any recent software upgrade left different Dovecot components in inconsistent state. (e.g. compare the installed version of all software packages.)

Comment: I tried to update version from v.2.3.17 to v.2.3.19 many times but it's not update.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Dovecot by using `./build/dovecot` and it is updated to the latest version and the issue was solved. However, I still cannot login via DirectAdmin and it shows the error that cannot connect IMAP server.